# How to do a localized Contrast Enhancement In a scanned Image Using OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contrast

I was working on a project I wanted to perform a localized contrast enhancement / adaptive contrast enhancement on a couple of images. I have tried thresholding but it is affecting the text of the image. I am attaching the images below

Source: [ImageHere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygEuA.jpg)

Result: [ImageHere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZINi.jpg)

Global contrast and other features are not working. Please do not suggest `CLAHE` It is giving very weird results. Please help me thank you.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code writing service - assuming you've written some code to try solve your problem, please edit your code into your question as a [mre] and explain what you've already tried to improve the output. Also there are many many results for a search for __opencv contrast enhancement__ so please describe what research you've already done, the most promising results you found, and why you weren't able to get good enough results - i.e. why you're asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV using division normalization and some sharpening.

- Read the input
- Convert to grayscale
- Blur the image
- Divide the grayscale image by the blurred image
- Apply sharpening (as desired)
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.filters as filters

# read the image
img = cv2.imread('math_questions.jpg')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# blur
smooth = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (95,95), 0)

# divide gray by morphology image
division = cv2.divide(gray, smooth, scale=255)

# sharpen using unsharp masking
result = filters.unsharp_mask(division, radius=1.5, amount=1.5, multichannel=False, preserve_range=False)
result = (255*result).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('math_question_division.jpg',division)
cv2.imwrite('math_question_division_sharpen.jpg',result)

# show results
cv2.imshow('smooth', smooth)  
cv2.imshow('division', division)  
cv2.imshow('result', result)  
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Division image:

[image]

Sharpened result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, your answer has really helped, it gave the exact result I asked in this question. However, It does not work uniformly in all scenarios. I have posted a new question with more samples. If possible please help me with that question I have spend so many days but I found no answer to my problems. Thanks in advance.
Here is the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63261234/localized-adaptive-contrast-enhancement-on-opencv-and-python