# Localized Adaptive Contrast enhancement on opencv and python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, contrast

I am trying to do image enhancement on different types of images. I have tried a lot of different methods but usually, it works only on one image but fails on a different image. I am new to Image Processing so it difficult for me to understand How it needs to be done. I am posting the input images and desired output.

Input 1:

[image: Input1]

output 1:

[image: Output1]

Input 2:

[image: Input2]

output 2:

[image: Output2]

Input 3:

[image: Input3]

output 3:

[image: Output3]

Input 4:

[Input4](https://ibb.co/rvBd1yv)

Output 4:

[image: Output4]

I have tried `CLAHE`,`Adaptive Thresholding`,`Histogram Equilization`, `Auto Brightness and Contrast adjustment`, `Adaptive Integral Enhancement`, and many more things. Nothing is working on all the images. My assumption is I need to implement some kind of Local Adaptive Contrast Enhancement, But then again I may be wrong. It would be of a great help if anyone could help me out with this problem.

Comment: Are you searching for a single method which enhance all images?

Comment: Ideally yes. I am looking for a method that would work on all these images

Comment: The technique needs to process black text on near-white background. Convert to grayscale first and then invert as needed

Comment: Hi, could you please help me with this. I have spent almost a couple of week now I am no where clear to the solutions. I am new to image processing, I really have no idea how do i get this result. Searched the whole internet and didn't find promising leads.

Comment: Imo this is a difficult task because one single method should work on all the very different images. I think you could use a method like CLAHE but you need to determine the parameters for every image automatically. Thus, you will need to analyze the image (colorspace, size of image, textsize ...) before using your method. Maybe you could also work in the frequency domain.

Answer (score 0):

As fmw42 said, you potentially need to work on gray level images. So the suggestion was to convert to grayscale and invert as needed. I can suggest that you convert to Y Cb Br and apply on Y, and keep Cb Cr as is and see whether this works. This is the method I would use, say, to apply histogram equalization to a color image.
CLAHE should do the trick for the gray level work.